# Copy the files in sub-directory with logging using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, directory, subdirectory

My requirement to copy the files from sub-directory and place it in a specific folder using a batch file. I have achieved using the below query

```
FOR /R "SourceFolder" %%i IN (*.pdf, *.txt, *.doc) DO COPY "%%i" "DestinationFolder" /Y
```

I need to log along with file & path in log file. I tried the below codes to achieve but it is not working

```
FOR /R "SourceFolder" %%i IN (*.pdf, *.txt, *.doc) DO (COPY "%%i" "DestinationFolder" /Y echo %%i) >> logfile.log

FOR /R "SourceFolder" %%i IN (*.pdf, *.txt, *.doc) DO (COPY "%%i" "DestinationFolder" /Y echo %%i >> logfile.log)

FOR /R "SourceFolder" %%i IN (*.pdf, *.txt, *.doc) DO (echo %%i >> logfile.log COPY "%%i" "DestinationFolder" /Y)
```

Comment: Just use `ROBOCOPY`.

Comment: @Squashman, Will i am able to log with `ROBOCOPY`

Comment: There is a whole section dedicated to logging options in the help file for `ROBOCOPY`.

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `robocopy /?` and output is the help for this command. You can alternatively also read [SS64 - ROBOCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) documentation or Microsoft's [ROBOCOPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) documentation. The documentations on SS64 for Windows commands are usually the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example batch file example to aid you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Src=C:\Users\Venkatesh\Documents"
Set "Dst=D:\Backups\Venkatesh\Docs"
Set "Log=C:\Users\Venkatesh\Desktop\Output.log"
RoboCopy /S "%Src%" "%Dst%" *.doc *.pdf *.txt /XJ /NP /NC /LOG:"%Log%" /TEE
Pause
```

*Modify the paths on lines `2`, `3` & `4` as necessary for your environment, and select the most appropriate options according to the output from `RoboCopy /?`*

Answer (score 1):

Would this be acceptable for achieving the logging you want?  The "@" will suppress echoing the "for" command, but each iteration of the loop will echo the resulting command (use 1 % - %i - when typing directly in a command window, use %%i in a batch script):

```
@echo on
@for /R "src" %%i IN (*.pdf *.txt *.doc) do copy "%%i" "dest" /Y >> logfile.log
```

Or, there are two ways to do something closer to exactly what you had.  "&" is the command shell command separator:

```
for /R "src" %%i IN (*.pdf *.txt *.doc) do (copy "%%i" "dest" /Y & echo %%i) >> logfile.log
```

Or the commands can appear on separate lines:

```
for /R "src" %%i IN (*.pdf *.txt *.doc) do (
  copy "%%i" "dest" /Y
  echo %%i
) >> logfile.log
```

After you enter the "for" line ending in "(", the shell will prompt you with "More?" as it waits for the end of the command, signalled by ')'.